# Cannot change cameraFlashMode for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a button on my custom camera overlay that invokes this method:

```
- (void) changeFlash:(id)sender
{
    //UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff  = -1,
    //UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto = 0,
    //UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn   = 1
    NSLog(@"before %d", self.picker.cameraFlashMode);
    switch (self.picker.cameraFlashMode) {
        case UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto:
            [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashOn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
            break;
        case UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn:
            [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashOff"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
            break;

        case UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff:
            [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashAuto"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"after %d", self.picker.cameraFlashMode);

}
```

self.picker.cameraFlashMode is always 0, before and after changing it. What am I doing wrong?

Also, the flash never works, even though it's supposedly stuck in UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto.

Comment: Check if self.picker is nil.

Comment: @soleil i had camera flash issues. i copied your method. and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I feel like it's iOS 7.1 i'm having the same issue here

Comment: Im forcing camera flash mode to On which == 1 and nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.picker is nil. This is a common mistake, and you need to check this often, because, unlike Java and other languages, it's valid to send a message to nil in Objective-C.

Comment: In my case the picker is not equal to nil, and I noticed the problem occurs on iphone 4 and not on iphone 5.
I created an other question:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403092/cannot-change-cameraflashmode-for-uiimagepickercontroller-iphone-4-custom-camera)