# Cannot change cameraFlashMode for UIImagePickerController iphone 4 custom cameraOverlayView

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-4

**Question**: *Why imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode always returns 0 on iphone 4 and returns correct values with iphone 5 ?*

I init my UIImagePickerController and set the cameraFlashMode to UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn:

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"];
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
[rest of overlay creation...]
```

Then when the flash button of my custom overlay is pressed, this method is fired:
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot below the value of cameraFlashMode is correct in the 'variables view' but returns 0 with NSLog and imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode

```
NSLog(@"current cameraFlashMode=%d", imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode); //returns 0 (iphone 4)
```

[image: log and console debug from iphone4]

However on the iphone 5 the value is accessible without problem:

```
NSLog(@"current cameraFlashMode=%d", imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode); //returns 1 (iphone 5)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an iOS7.1 bug

Comment: I guess you're right, I tested again with both phones on 7.1, same problem..